# Embedded browser in Adobe AIR/Flex - cache javascript and css files?

Tags: javascript, css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm running a desktop application written in adobe actionscript/air flex.

Some webpages are embedded via the `mx:HTML` component.

Question: does this component provide caching of `js` and `css` files from the page? If yes, are they cached only as long as the application is running? Or do they survive application restarts?

Answer (score 0):

The Flex `HTML` component wraps [`HTMLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html), which has [`cacheResponse`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#cacheResponse) and [`useCache`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#useCache) to control caching. When cached, it uses the "operating system's HTTP cache", so I wouldn't assume that it will *always* work any particular way, it's up to the OS and user preferences.

Comment: when I load a webpage, how can I verify inside the HTMLLoader of the embedded resources like js and css files have been cached or downloaded on request?

Comment: You want to know from AIR/AS3, or you just want to know how it's working on a particular machine for debugging purposes? You could use an HTTP proxy like Charles to see what AIR is doing.

Comment: I'd like to know this both in general for AIR/Flex, but also on particular PCs. Thanks, I'll have a look into charles.